# Fix duplicate name situation due to entities created before Orion 0.17.0

Tags: fiware-orion

Since Orion 0.17.0 attribute type is no longer used as attribute "identification key". However, I have entities created with a pre-0.17.0 version that have attributes with the same name and different types. For example, the following entity, which have "ActivePower" duplicated:

```
> db.entities.findOne({"_id.type": "Regulator", "_id.id": "OUTSMART.RG_LAS_LLAMAS_01", "_id.servicePath": "/"})
{
    "_id" : {
        "type" : "Regulator",
        "id" : "OUTSMART.RG_LAS_LLAMAS_01",
        "servicePath" : "/"
    },
    "attrs" : [
        {
            "name" : "TimeInstant",
            "value" : "2015-04-27T01:51:36.000000Z",
            "type" : "urn:x-ogc:def:trs:IDAS:1.0:ISO8601",
            "modDate" : 1430092302
        },
        {
            "name" : "ActivePower",
            "value" : "11778",
            "type" : "urn:x-ogc:def:phenomenon:Outsmart:1.0:ActivePower",
            "modDate" : 1430092302
        },
        {
            "name" : "ReactivePower",
            "value" : "8414",
            "type" : "urn:x-ogc:def:phenomenon:Outsmart:1.0:ReactivePower",
            "modDate" : 1430092302
        },
        {
            "name" : "electricPotential",
            "value" : "231",
            "type" : "urn:x-ogc:def:phenomenon:IDAS:1.0:electricPotential",
            "modDate" : 1430092302
        },
        {
            "name" : "electricCurrent",
            "value" : "20890",
            "type" : "urn:x-ogc:def:phenomenon:IDAS:1.0:electricCurrent",
            "modDate" : 1430092302
        },
        {
            "name" : "Latitud",
            "value" : "43.4716987609863",
            "type" : "urn:x-ogc:def:phenomenon:IDAS:1.0:latitude",
            "modDate" : 1414522843
        },
        {
            "name" : "Longitud",
            "value" : "-3.80692005157471",
            "type" : "urn:x-ogc:def:phenomenon:IDAS:1.0:longitude",
            "modDate" : 1401818472
        },
        {
            "name" : "ActivePower",
            "creDate" : 1393420396,
            "value" : "11778.2",
            "type" : "float",
            "modDate" : 1430092302
        }
    ],
    "modDate" : 1430092302
}
```

How can I adapt that entity to work with Orion 0.17.0 and beyond?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to edit the entity using mongo console, to remove all the "duplicated" attributes with the same name and leave only one. In the example above we have one ActivePower with type `urn:x-ogc:def:phenomenon:Outsmart:1.0:ActivePower` and other with type `float`. Let's assume we want to kept the first one.

First of all, stop Orion and [take a backup of the database](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide#Backup). If something gets wrong while you edit the entity, you could need that backup to go back the initial status and try again.

Next, run mongo console (let's assume that your DB is named "orion") and get the entity to modify using `findOne()` operation. Let's store it in the `doc` variable.

```
# mongo orion
> doc = db.entities.findOne({"_id.type": "Regulator", "_id.id": "OUTSMART.RG_LAS_LLAMAS_01", "_id.servicePath": "/"})
...
```

Now, identify the position within the `attrs` array of the attribute to remove, taking into account that the position of the first element in the vector is 0 (and not 1). Looking to the above example, the attribute to remove is the 7-th. Check that printing the attribute:

```
> doc.attrs[7]
{
    "name" : "ActivePower",
    "creDate" : 1393420396,
    "value" : "11778.2",
    "type" : "float",
    "modDate" : 1430092302
}
```

Use `splice()` function to remove the attribute from `doc`, using as first parameter the position of the attribute and as second parameter 1. Print the `doc` value to check that it has been removed:

```
> doc.attrs.splice(7, 1)
...
> doc
```

Repeat the above operation as many time as you need to remove all duplicated (in the example case, there is only one duplicated). When you are done, save the new version of the entity in the DB:

```
> db.entities.save(doc)
```